# Asus T100 won't boot - LED blinks 5 times

Tags: boot, power-supply, battery, power, asus

I've been using my ASUS T100 for more than 5 years. Today, I started it as usual, but only noticed the LED blinking 5 times. When charged fully, it blinks 5 times in white and when unplugged, it blinks 5 times in orange color when holding the power button/ power button + windows button.

I do remember changing the charger recently but not sure if that was the cause of this. The new charger I used is also a smartphone charger which should work. But now I'm out of options and there's no service server near me which could solve this issue. I also charged the T100 to 100% (till I see white LED) before trying the same button hold sequence - but still, nothing :(

Is there any way I can diagnose this issue? whether it's due to a bad battery? I tried googling for LED codes for T100 but could not find any :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down the power button for 30 seconds, then release. Wait 10 seconds, then hold down the power button again. The laptop should boot.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, but since I'm not able to turn it on, is there a way to drain the battery fully? 

I also opened the back case to see if there was a way to power it directly, but unfortunately, could not find any such facility. When I removed the battery connector and plugged in the USB, the orange light just kept flashing every 1 sec.

Comment: Oh, wait, I wasn't meant to say to drain your battery, you can't drain the battery of a laptop that doesn't power on. Whoops, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Try the solution above, then let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried your solution - still wasn't able to boot the laptop :(
The LED blinks 5 times rapidly and that's the only thing I can notice. Any other ideas? 
I'm fine with removing the backcover also (already did it once) for any checking purposes.

Comment: You mention that you have changed the charger recently. I believe this may have something to do with the charger. How long were you using the new charger until this issue began to occur?

Comment: I used it only once. It was a Samsung fast charger that came with the box of a Note10.

Comment: Aha, that was the cause of the issue. Samsung fast chargers send a higher wattage than your laptop is rated for, and when some laptops (including yours) detects a higher current than suitable for it, it will, essentially, go into a sort of safe mode to protect itself. Never use a charger that isn't compatible with your machine. Your laptop is probably fixable.  You will need to drain the battery completely, which will take it out of the safe mode and allow it to boot again. You will then need to purchase a charger compatible with your laptop, charge it, and it will turn on.

Comment: It was an urgent situation and I did not have any other chargers around so I thought the laptop would take care of the wattage difference :/  I now have the ASUS charger that came with the laptop and will definitely remember this instance! 

I'm now hopeful based on your comment! Any ideas on how to drain the battery fully? can taking the battery out and doing something with it externally help?

Comment: Let me just clarify to make sure it was the charger, was the last charger you charged the laptop with, while it was still working, the Samsung one?

Comment: Yes! I can confirm that just after the last time it was working, I charged it with a Samsung charger and since then I've only see the LED blink 5 times and no boot or anything or the screen.

Comment: Oh I might have confused - I have only used samsung charger ONCE. Since I bought the laptop, I've only used the ASUS charger. After I used the Samsung charger, I was not able to turn on the laptop

Comment: Do you still require assistance?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I didn't operate the laptop since my last comment so I just took it out to test it again and it seems the battery had completely drained (was not able to turn it on). I just put on charge with the official cable + charger (can see the orange light). I will update with a new comment after the charging process completes (orange->white light) and let you know if I can turn it on now.

Comment: Ok, that's fine

Comment: The laptop has been in charge for more than 6 hrs. It's still orange. I don't think this battery is salvageable. Do you have any other suggestions? I'm thinking of just buying a new battery.

Comment: Yes, this is probably a problem with the battery. I'd advise replacing the battery. Please click the green tick and up arrow next to my answer to let others know that this question has been answered and requires no further action. Hope it goes well.